Flutter Failing to Install \flutter-apk\app-debug.apk
So I am new to flutter development for Android on VSCode, and I have followed all of the steps on the official Flutter tutorial (all of https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/windows/mobile?tab=later-start and till Step 5 of "Run Your Sample Flutter App) at https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/test-drive). When I tried to run with debugging the sample app on VSCode, I get the following error message:
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
√ Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk
cmd: Failure calling service activity: Broken pipe (32)
Error: ADB exited with exit code 1
Performing Streamed Install

adb: failed to install C:\Users\baasi\test_drive\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk: cmd: Can't find service: package
Error launching application on sdk gphone64 x86 64.

So I ran flutter -doctor on PowerShell, and here are the results:
PS C:\Users\baasi\test_drive> flutter doctor -v
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.22.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22631.3737], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 3.22.2 on channel stable at C:\dev\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 761747bfc5 (2 weeks ago), 2024-06-05 22:15:13 +0200
    • Engine revision edd8546116
    • Dart version 3.4.3
    • DevTools version 2.34.3

[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 35.0.0)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\baasi\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-35, build-tools 35.0.0
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1\jbr\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.10+0--11609105)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[X] Chrome - develop for the web (Cannot find Chrome executable at .\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe)
    ! Cannot find Chrome. Try setting CHROME_EXECUTABLE to a Chrome executable.

[X] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps
    X Visual Studio not installed; this is necessary to develop Windows apps.
      Download at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.
      Please install the "Desktop development with C++" workload, including all of its default components

[√] Android Studio (version 2024.1)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.10+0--11609105)

[√] VS Code (version 1.90.2)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\baasi\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.90.0

[√] Connected device (3 available)
    • sdk gphone64 x86 64 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x64    • Android 15 (API 35) (emulator)
    • Windows (desktop)            • windows       • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22631.3737]
    • Edge (web)                   • edge          • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 126.0.2592.61

[√] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.

The issues shown seemingly do not have to do with the Android development functionality of flutter, so I am unsure what to do.

Do you have an emulator running or a device connected?

Yeah, I have an emulator running.

Make sure android studio isn't open and then try to restart ADB using:
adb kill-server

can also try to start emulator on cold boot.
